# Bound of the norm of a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Question: Consider a norm on vector space R^n. Prove that it is bounded on the unit sphere.

Attempt: I know that normed vector spaces correspond to unit balls, which are bounded by the unit sphere, but I'm struggling proving the above statement using the general properties of a norm (triangle property, scalar multiplication, etc.)

Comment: First, can you prove that any norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continuous? second, are you familiar with the fact that continuous functions on compact sets are bounded?

Comment: @TomAriel I've proven that it is continuous and that fact makes sense. So since the norm is continuous, and since the unit sphere is compact, then it must be bounded on the unit sphere?

Comment: Thats exactly right. You can actually prove a slightly stronger statment using this - for any 2 norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ there are some $c_{1}, c_{2} > 0$ s.t $ c_{1} \norm v \norm_{1} \leq \norm v \norm_{2} \leq c_{2} \norm v \norm_{1}$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $

Answer (score 0):

Is the unit sphere here referring to the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$? If not, the result is trivial, as the norm is equal to one everywhere on the unit sphere.

Denoting the norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\|\cdot\|$, and the standard norm by $\|\cdot\|_E$, I will denote $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|_E = 1 \}.$

I see in the comments that you have proven that any norm on a finite dimensional space is continuous, so using that continuous functions on compact sets attain their maximum, we get that there is $x_0 \in S$ such that for all $x\in S$:

$$ \|x\| \leq \|x_0\| = C, $$

so the norm is bounded on $S$.